# resolve lazy-loading images with parcel-bundler by using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, parcel

It seems parcel does not recognizes the image when **"src"** path is replaced with **"data-src"** attribute!

Hope this helps!

This is my HTML code:
[Lazy-loading HTML Markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CptlB.png)
Javsascript with intersectionObserverAPI:
[Lazy-loading with intersectionObserverAPI][2]
When the image isIntersecting I'm removing the lazy-image class after the "load" event.
[CSS lazy-image class][3]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1OO.pngenter code here
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOoSZ.png

This is JS Code:
/* Lazy Loading Hidden Images of Signin and SignUp Forms */

```
const imgTarget = document.querySelector(".more__itf__img");
```

// console.log(imgTargetsArray)

```
const loadingImage = (entries, observer) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    console.log(entry);

    if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;

    // Replace image "src" attribute with "data-src" attribute.
    // Loading of images happens behind the scenes, and once its finished
    // loading that image it will emit the "load" event.
    entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;
    // Listening for "load" event.
    entry.target.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    entry.target.classList.remove("lazy-image");
   });

   observer.unobserve(entry.target);
};

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver(loadingImage, {
    root: null,
    threshold: 0.15,
    // loading lazy-images before reaching the threshold value.
    rootMargin: "200px",
});

if(imgTarget){
    imgObserver.observe(imgTarget);
}
```

HTML Markup:

```
<section class="more__itf aos_element">
    <img
        src="./images/blur_img.svg"
        data-src="./images/more_itf_purple.svg"
        alt="more__itf"
        class="more__itf__img lazy-image"
    />
    <h3 class="more__itf__text">more in the future...</h3>
</section>
```

CSS Style:
/* Lazy-image loading */

```
.lazy-image {
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: Could you just add the code into the question instead of linking them as screenshots?

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope it helps.